# How to install Unity3d game engine on Ubuntu

Tags: wine

I downloaded unity 3d game engine from [the official website](http://unity3d.com/unity/download).

I tried to install using this command:

```
wine unity*.exe
```

Done.

Then trying to open I get the following error:

```
error initializing license system
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [article](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Running_Unity_on_Linux_through_Wine) useful for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following key to your wine registry:

```
wine reg add 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' /v ProductId /t REG_SZ /d 12345-oem-0000001-54321
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I tried it

Comment: @kamil maybe if you try to remove your wine config (in `~/.wine`) and install it over again, but before the first unity run, add the given key. The thing is, that message is because unity cannot find the license key, at least for me it worked

Comment: It works for me!

Comment: Works for me too.  Didn't need to reinstall.

Comment: It was that easy!? I did it a much, much more complicated way. That would have been good to know when i set up unity lol

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I just installed a 32 bit version of Unity3D, even though my system was x64, it fixed the problem.